# Interfacing TFT LCD Module with Arduino

Tags: arduino, lcd, tft

I recently found a 3.5in QVGA TFT LCD module (Stellaris LaunchPad LCD Boosterpack EB-LM4F120-L35) which is meant to be a booster pack for the EK-LM4F120XL development board by TI. It is supposed to stack directly onto the control board, but I want to connect it to an arduino. The connections on the board are unfamiliar to me, and I haven't been able to figure out what protocol it uses to drive the screen or how it would connect to the pins on the arduino. Any kind of guidance would be appreciated.

Here is the datasheet for the LCD: https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1653560.pdf

And here is the link for the dev board: https://www.ti.com/tool/EK-LM4F120XL

Thank you.

Comment: It is unclear what kind of help you need or with what. The LCD module data sheet with the schematics say that the LCD is a K350QVG-V2-F for which a datasheet is available and the schematics show it is configured for a 8-bit 8080 interface mode.

Comment: @Justme The OP appears to want someone to thoroughly review all the pinouts and listed products and work out a precise electrical interface that will serve all current and future requirements and then move on to discussing the required algorithms and operating environments and various software design concerns so that they can succeed with whatever it is they have in mind or may yet have, at some time in the future, as they learn more. Something like that. A novella, perhaps?

Comment: Here you can find a driver library for the MSP430F5529 and MSP432P401R LaunchPads as a starting point: https://github.com/Andy4495/Kentec_35_Parallel.

Comment: I wasn't looking for any kind of expansive guide or thorough explanation. Other devices I've looked at normally use SPI or UART but some of the connections with this screen looked unusual to me, so I was mostly looking for confirmation on that. I think the driver library could have what I'm looking for.